# Xcode C++ 20 support for Import / Modules

Tags: c++, xcode, module, clang, c++20

I've been trolling through the messages and haven't found an updated answer to Xcode support for C++20 modules.   Apologies if I missed it.

Right now, all I'm trying to do is use the import directive to import a C++ Standard Library file.

```
import <iostream>;
import <string>;
import <memory>;
```

This produces an error of "Use of undeclared identifier 'iostream'" as well as "Use of undeclared identifier 'string'" (same for memory).

For my Project Build Settings I have:

**My C++ Language Dialect:** GNU++20 [-std=gnu++20]

**Compile for C/C++/Objective-C:** Default compiler (Apple Clang)

Would appreciate help with this.   Thank you.

Comment: That's not how you import the C++ libraries. C++20 does **not** include modules for the standard libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.   The C++ book I'm reading uses the exact same syntax for including those files.

Comment: "*Apple Clang*" I was under the impression that this compiler doesn't support modules as of yet.

Comment: @ChrisMM: "*That's not how you import the C++ libraries.*" It's *supposed* to be able to work. The standard even [specifically states that they can be imported as header units](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/module.import#5.sentence-3). Now, many implementations have *problems* implementing this, but it is still a thing that's supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments.   FYI - I found this page detailing C++20 and C++23 feature support (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).   It cites only MSVC seems to have initial support for Standard Template Modules.   Apple's Clang compiler has "partial" support as of v10.0.0.1.   I'm at Clang version 14.0.0.

Comment: I still consider Xcode as having **no** support for C++20 modules. And also of course no C++23 `std` module. I have been waiting for that support for several years: maybe in 2024 or 2025?

Comment: If the compilers still have no finished support for modules, you can expect the toolchain to take at least 3 years to implement it. CMake is making a progress already but i haven't heared of XCode. I assume here again it will take 10 years from standard to widespread usage, which is despite all the claims of "internet" time is just normal.